# Acumatica: How to create new customer in ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, api, soap, acumatica

I need to create Customer using SOAP API in ruby (we want to consume Acumatica api from Ruby on Rails project).

Currently my code using Savon gem looks like this:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: 'wsdl.wsdl') # sample wsdl path

response = client.call :login, message: { name: '', password: '' }
auth_cookies = response.http.cookies


class ServiceRequest

  def to_s
    builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
    builder.instruct!(:xml, encoding: 'UTF-8')

    # ... problem is here, I don't know how XML request should look like

    builder
  end

end

p client.call :submit, message: ServiceRequest.new, cookies: auth_cookies
```

Problem is that, I don't know how XML request should look like.

C# requests looks like this (just piece of sample from docs):

```
PO302000result = context.PO302000Submit(
      new Command[]
      { new Value { Value = "PORE000079", LinkedCommand =
                                       PO302000.DocumentSummary.ReceiptNbr},
        new Value { Value = "OK", LinkedCommand =
               PO302000.AddPurchaseOrderLine.ServiceCommands.DialogAnswer,
               PO302000.Actions.AddPOOrderLine, new Key { Value = "='PORG000084'", FieldName = Commit = true },
   PO302000.AddPurchaseOrderLine.OrderNbr.FieldName, ObjectName =
              PO302000.AddPurchaseOrderLine.OrderNbr.ObjectName },
       new Key { Value = "='CPU00004'", FieldName =
              PO302000.AddPurchaseOrderLine.InventoryID.FieldName, ObjectName =
              PO302000.AddPurchaseOrderLine.InventoryID.ObjectName },
      new Value{ Value = "True", LinkedCommand =
          PO302000.AddPurchaseOrderLine.Selected, Commit = true },
                                PO302000.Actions.AddPOOrderLine2
       new Key{ Value = "='CPU00004'", FieldName =
     PO302000.DocumentDetails_.InventoryID.FieldName, ObjectName =
                 PO302000.DocumentDetails_.InventoryID.ObjectName},
     new Value{ Value = "1.00", LinkedCommand =
            PO302000.DocumentDetails_.ReceiptQty, Commit = true},
    // the next part of code is needed if you use Serial items
    PO302000.BinLotSerialNumbers.ServiceCommands.NewRow,
   new Value { Value = "R01", LinkedCommand =
                         PO302000.BinLotSerialNumbers.Location },
   PO302000.Actions.Save
  } );
```

But I don't know what kind of XML this code produce. It looks like we have Commands array with Values and then action name. But what XML does this kind of code renders? Maybe some C# or Java folks can copy me xml requests samples that are rendered by that kind of code?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually  'mumboe-soap4r' or 'soap2r' or 'soap4r' doesn't work with Acumatica soap API. They are too old and buggy.

In the end I am using Savon gem (version 2). I am creating message using XmlMarkup class. But how I know what XML should I create? In order to know this I am creating soap request in .net , then I see what right XML request looks like and only then I am creating soap request using Savon gem. Too much work, but I don't know better way for now. It works.

In order for Savon to work with Acumatica API I set next options:

```
client = Savon.client do

  wsdl                    'http://path/Soap/AR303000.asmx?wsdl'
  log                     true
  namespaces              'xmlns:soap' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
  env_namespace           'soap'

  namespace_identifier    nil
  element_form_default    ''

end
```

Don't forget to pass auth cookies

```
response = client.call(:login, message: { name: '', password: '' })
auth_cookies = response.http.cookies
```

Build your customer creating xml, then do submit

```
m = build_create_submit(customer_name)

response = client.call(:submit, message: m, cookies: auth_cookies)

# get customer id of newly created customer
customer_id = response.try(:hash).try(:[], :envelope).
                       try(:[], :body).
                       try(:[], :submit_response).
                       try(:[], :submit_result).
                       try(:[], :content).
                       try(:[], :customer_summary).
                       try(:[], :customer_id).
                       try(:[], :value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's a bad idea to generate XML SOAP package manually, you should have some wrapper on your side, which have to simplify your code.

Comment: There are no good wrapper for acumatica API, soap4r, soap2r, mumboe-soap4r doesn't work with Acumatica API. In the end I am creating XML requests manually using Savon gem. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, the C# code below + XML SOAP request

```
            Content[] result = context.Submit(
            new Command[] 
                {                                                    
                    new Value { Value = "PORE000079", LinkedCommand = PO302000.DocumentSummary.ReceiptNbr}
                    ,new Value { Value = "OK", LinkedCommand = PO302000.AddPurchaseOrderLine.ServiceCommands.DialogAnswer, Commit = true }
                    ,PO302000.Actions.AddPOOrderLine                                                
                    ,new Key { Value = "='PORG000077'", FieldName = PO302000.AddPurchaseOrderLine.OrderNbr.FieldName, ObjectName = PO302000.AddPurchaseOrderLine.OrderNbr.ObjectName }
                    ,new Key { Value = "='CPU00004'", FieldName = PO302000.AddPurchaseOrderLine.InventoryID.FieldName, ObjectName = PO302000.AddPurchaseOrderLine.InventoryID.ObjectName }
                    ,new Value{ Value = "True", LinkedCommand = PO302000.AddPurchaseOrderLine.Selected, Commit = true }
                    ,PO302000.Actions.AddPOOrderLine2                        
                    ,new Key{ Value = "='CPU00004'", FieldName = PO302000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID.FieldName, ObjectName = PO302000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID.ObjectName}
                    ,new Value{ Value = "1.00", LinkedCommand = PO302000.DocumentDetails.ReceiptQty, Commit = true}         

                    // the next part of code is needed if you use Serial items                            
                    ,PO302000.BinLotSerialNumbers.ServiceCommands.NewRow
                    ,new Value { Value = "R01", LinkedCommand = PO302000.BinLotSerialNumbers.Location }
                    ,new Value { Value = "1.00", LinkedCommand = PO302000.BinLotSerialNumbers.Quantity, Commit = true }
                    ,new Value { Value = "25.00", LinkedCommand = PO302000.DocumentDetails.UnitCost, Commit = true }
                    ,new Key { Value = "='CPU00004'", FieldName = PO302000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID.FieldName, ObjectName = PO302000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID.ObjectName }
                    ,new Value { Value = "0.00", LinkedCommand = PO302000.DocumentDetails.ReceiptQty, Commit = true }

                    ,PO302000.Actions.Save
                }
        );








<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><Submit xmlns="http://www.acumatica.com/typed/"><commands><Command xsi:type="Value"><Value>PORE000079</Value><LinkedCommand xsi:type="Field"><FieldName>ReceiptNbr</FieldName><ObjectName>Document</ObjectName><Value>ReceiptNbr</Value><Commit>true</Commit><LinkedCommand xsi:type="Action"><FieldName>cancel</FieldName><ObjectName>Document</ObjectName><LinkedCommand xsi:type="Key"><FieldName>ReceiptNbr</FieldName><ObjectName>Document</ObjectName><Value>=[Document.ReceiptNbr]</Value><LinkedCommand xsi:type="Key"><FieldName>ReceiptType</FieldName><ObjectName>Document</ObjectName><Value>=[Document.ReceiptType]</Value></LinkedCommand></LinkedCommand></LinkedCommand></LinkedCommand></Command><Command xsi:type="Value"><Value>OK</Value><Commit>true</Commit><LinkedCommand xsi:type="Answer"><ObjectName>poLinesSelection</ObjectName><Value>='Yes'</Value></LinkedCommand></Command><Command xsi:type="Action"><FieldName>AddPOOrderLine</FieldName><ObjectName>Document</ObjectName><Commit>true</Commit></Command><Command xsi:type="Key"><FieldName>OrderNbr</FieldName><ObjectName>poLinesSelection</ObjectName><Value>='PORG000077'</Value></Command><Command xsi:type="Key"><FieldName>InventoryID</FieldName><ObjectName>poLinesSelection</ObjectName><Value>='CPU00004'</Value></Command><Command xsi:type="Value"><Value>True</Value><Commit>true</Commit><LinkedCommand xsi:type="Field"><FieldName>Selected</FieldName><ObjectName>poLinesSelection</ObjectName><Value>Selected</Value><Commit>true</Commit></LinkedCommand></Command><Command xsi:type="Action"><FieldName>AddPOOrderLine2</FieldName><ObjectName>Document</ObjectName><Commit>true</Commit></Command><Command xsi:type="Key"><FieldName>InventoryID</FieldName><ObjectName>transactions</ObjectName><Value>='CPU00004'</Value></Command><Command xsi:type="Value"><Value>1.00</Value><Commit>true</Commit><LinkedCommand xsi:type="Field"><FieldName>ReceiptQty</FieldName><ObjectName>transactions</ObjectName><Value>ReceiptQty</Value><Commit>true</Commit></LinkedCommand></Command><Command xsi:type="NewRow"><ObjectName>splits</ObjectName></Command><Command xsi:type="Value"><Value>R01</Value><LinkedCommand xsi:type="Field"><FieldName>LocationID</FieldName><ObjectName>splits</ObjectName><Value>Location</Value></LinkedCommand></Command><Command xsi:type="Value"><Value>1.00</Value><Commit>true</Commit><LinkedCommand xsi:type="Field"><FieldName>Qty</FieldName><ObjectName>splits</ObjectName><Value>Quantity</Value></LinkedCommand></Command><Command xsi:type="Value"><Value>25.00</Value><Commit>true</Commit><LinkedCommand xsi:type="Field"><FieldName>CuryUnitCost</FieldName><ObjectName>transactions</ObjectName><Value>UnitCost</Value></LinkedCommand></Command><Command xsi:type="Key"><FieldName>InventoryID</FieldName><ObjectName>transactions</ObjectName><Value>='CPU00004'</Value></Command><Command xsi:type="Value"><Value>0.00</Value><Commit>true</Commit><LinkedCommand xsi:type="Field"><FieldName>ReceiptQty</FieldName><ObjectName>transactions</ObjectName><Value>ReceiptQty</Value><Commit>true</Commit></LinkedCommand></Command><Command xsi:type="Action"><FieldName>Save</FieldName><ObjectName>Document</ObjectName></Command></commands></Submit></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

So in the end what I did:

```
gem install 'mumboe-soap4r'  # not soap4r, 
                             # because soap4r is old and bugged with newer rubies
```

Then I ran

```
wsdl2ruby.rb --wsdl customer.wsdl --type client
```

Where wsdl2ruby.rb is installed together with mumboe-soap4r gem. Replace customer.wsdl with path to your wsdl, could be URL or file system path.

After running this command next files were created:

```
default.rb
defaultMappingRegistry.rb
defaultDriver.rb
ScreenClient.rb
```

Using those files you can write code similar to C# code or php code to interact with acumatica API:

```
require_relative  'defaultDriver'
require           'soap/wsdlDriver'

# this is my helper method to make life easier
def prepare_value(value, command, need_commit = false, ignore = false)
  value_command                   = Value.new
  value_command.value             = value
  value_command.linkedCommand     = command
  value_command.ignoreError       = ignore        unless ignore.nil?
  value_command.commit            = need_commit   unless need_commit.nil?
  value_command
end

soap_client = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new('customer.wsdl').create_rpc_driver
soap_client.login(name: '', password: '').loginResult

screen = soap_client.getSchema(nil)
soap_client.clear(nil)
content = screen.getSchemaResult
# p schema

p customer      = content.customerSummary.customerID
p customer_name = content.customerSummary.customerName
country         = content.generalInfoMainAddress.country
customer_class  = content.generalInfoFinancialSettings.customerClass


commands = ArrayOfCommand.new
commands << prepare_value('ABBA',     customer_name)
commands << prepare_value('US',       country)
commands << prepare_value('MERCHANT', customer_class)
commands << content.actions.insert
commands << customer.clone                # to return

p commands

p soap_client.submit(commands)
```

Hope it will help someone.